# How to choose a media center remote with mouse pad to control my pc for Windows/Linux?

Tags: windows-media-center, remote-control, htpc, kodi, mythtv

My goal is to make my windows 7 mce htpc to use linux instead, I would like to use Mythtv and Xbmc to use my tv tuner and others sources. (tube sites, tv channels sites and others ...)

Answer (score 0):

My HTPC has the following specs.

```
Antec Fusion Pro Case
Intel Core i3 2100 Sandy Bridge Processor
128GB SSD (Primary HDD)
2TB x 2 RAID1 (Video Archives)
Logitech Harmony Remote (Controls HTPC/Receiver/TV)
ASUS P8Z68-V LX MotherBoard
4x2GB DDR3-1600RAM
Ceton InfiniTV4 PCIE (4 Tuners with MCard - Able to watch Premium Channels)
Windows 7 Ultimate
XBMC Plugin for WMC
Ceton Plugin for WMC
Wireless 2.4GHz Mouse
```

It's not the best and fastest computer in the world, but I have 10 second boots and able to use the remote for everything. It's easy to use (wife is not tech savvy). Redundancy on the video archives and switching applications and boots are a dream with the SSD.

Before my dog ate the wireless dongle, I did have an ASUS Media Center Keyboard that had a trackball built in which was extremely nice. Had the feel of an iPad when holding but a full physical keyboard. Came stock with my HTPC predecessor ASUS CS5110. When I met my wife, it was determined that I needed to move to just one remote and we keep the wireless mouse handy if something funky happens with the remote communication.

We are using integrated graphics via HDMI, but works great for streaming/tv/video playback.

Comment: I was trying this hack but the drivers don't seem to work :

http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=XBox_DVD_Remote

Comment: Interesting. I don't really own any gaming consoles so never had an xbox remote. the Harmony remotes are amazing. I got one of their cheaper ones, but does an excellent job.

Comment: the main trouble is getting an usb ir receiver and the remote ...

Comment: your dog literally ate the dongle?

Comment: She is a Rottweiler Doberman mix. Yes. It came out in her ...

Answer (score 0):

If your're using XBMC as frontend and you already have a tablet you could use it as a controller. Applications like Yatse work great

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.leetzone.android.yatsewidgetfree

I'm even using it on my phone.